# MatLab :: Assume and find different possible unknown variables of inequalities ,

Tags: matlab, find

I have inequalities with two unknown variables. So how could I assume one variable with different values and get the others?

For instance: `-15<10*x+2*y<20`.
How could I assume x=2, 3, and so on, and then find answer of (y) depending on the value of (x)?

I have been trying to apply the `assume` and `find` commands, but unfortunately, I could not. So I hope anyone could help me, please.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

I am new to Matlab, so I have been trying to apply solve, assume, and find commands

```
clear all; 
clc;
syms x y real;
z=solve(-15<10*x+2*y,[x y])
b=solve(10*x+2*y<20,[x y])

yinterval = [ z,b]
```

I expect the output: to assume x=different numbers and then y= be a list of possible results depending on the value of x

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

For each value of *x*, technically there are infinite values of *y* that satisfy those equations, so for my solution, I assumed *x* and *y* were integer values. As well, it appears that you want to give the program a set of *x* values and have it calculate *y* values for each *x* value. Instead of using the solve command, we can simply use a couple of loops to find all satisfactory integer values of *y* for each value of *x*.

To start, we need to make a results matrix to store each *x,y* pair that satisfies the equations you've given. This is called *pre-allocation*, as we're pre-allocating the space needed to store our answers. Using the equations, we can deduce that there will be 17 satisfactory *y* values per *x*. So, our first two lines of code will be initializing the desired *x*-values and the results matrix:

```
xVec = 1:5; %x-vector, change this to whatever x-values you want to test
results = zeros(length(xVec)*14, 2); %results matrix
```

Note: If you decide to iterate *x* or *y* by a value different than +1 (more on that later), you'll need to come up with a different method of creating this results matrix. You could also just not pre-allocate the results matrix, but your code will run slower as the size of the results matrix will be changing on each loop.

Next are the loops. Admittedly, this is not the most elegant solution, but it'll get the job done. First, we need an index to keep up with where we are in our results matrix. This is pretty easy, we'll just call it index and start at 1 (since MATLAB indexes from 1 in matrices. Remember that!):

```
index = 1; %index for results matrix
```

Next, we need to loop through each value in our *x*-vector. Simply use a for loop:

```
 for x = xVec
 ...
```

For each value of *x*, there is a minimum value of *y*. This value can be solved for in

> -15 < 10*x + 2*y   -->   -14 = 10*x + 2*y_min

So, simply solving for *y* gives us our next line of code:

```
    y = -7 - 5*x; %solving for y
```

Note: each time we iterate *x* in our for loop, a new starting value of *y* will be calculated.

Finally, we need to loop through values of *y* that still satisfy the inequalities given. This is performed through use of a while loop:

```
    while 10*x + 2*y > -15 && 10*x + 2*y < 20
    ...
```

Note: && is the 'and' statement while using loops. You can't use a single equation for this (i.e. you can't say something like -15 < x < 20, you have to split them up using &&).

Since we solved for the first value of *y*, we can go ahead and record the current *x* and *y* values in our results matrix:

```
        results(index, :) = [x, y]; %storing current x- and y-values
```

Then, we need to iterate *y*, as otherwise we'd be stuck in this while-loop forever.

```
        y = y + 1;
```

Note: You can iterate this *y*-value with whatever amount you want. I chose to iterate by 1 each time, as I assumed you wanted to find integer values. Just change the +1 to whatever value you want.

Finally, we iterate our index, so that the next pair of *x*,*y* values that satisfy our equations don't overwrite our previous solutions.

```
        index = index + 1;
```

All that's left is to close our loops and run! As I said, this isn't the most efficient solution, so I wouldn't use this for large amounts of *x*- and *y*-values. As well, like with iterating the *y*-values, the *x*-values can have any 'step-size' you want. As it's coded currently, it jumps +1 between each *x*, but changing the xVec input to any vector will still work (ex. xVec = 1:0.1:5; iterates the *x*-value by +0.1 each step instead of +1).

Here's the code all together, sans comments (since I wrote the comments while making the above code snippets):

```matlab
    xVec = 1:5;
    results = zeros(length(xVec)*14, 2);

    index = 1;
    for x = xVec
        y = -7 - 5*x;
        while 10*x + 2*y > -15 && 10*x + 2*y < 20
            results(index, :) = [x, y];
            y = y + 1;
            index = index + 1;
        end
    end
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your prompt reply. I am having a look, what about the following code, I have been trying to do it, however, I just have small question, would you mind helping me,

Comment: Below is the code 

clc;
syms x y real;
neg=solve(-15 == 10*x+2*y,y)
pos=solve(10*x+2*y == 20,y)
yinterval = [ neg,pos] 
myfunc(10)   % to see the results of neg, and pos if x=100 
%% Add function 
function myfunc(x)  
 
neg=input('enter equation ') % I have written yinterval(1) %% (got error of undefined variable )
pos=input('enter equation ') %% (got error of undefined variable )
 yin(:,1)=[cc,mm]
 end
ANy help!